# Confirmation dialogue on button click for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, razor

This might be a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer. I have a button which is making an ajax call and doing the functionality on click. But I need to restrict that by giving a confirmation pop up "Are you sure to delete this account?" with "Yes", "No" options. Im using a single button to delete/add accounts, so the text on confirmation dialogue should change accordingly.

```
<button type="submit" id="StatusChange" name="StatusChange" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
  "Click to Delete Account" 
</button>
```

```
$("#StatusChange").click(function () {
  var state = 'ACTIVE';
  var id = '12345';
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ChangeAccountStatus", "Account")',
    data: { currentStatus: state, accountId:id },
    success: function(data){
      location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercepting a jQuery.ajax() call with confirm()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384251/intercepting-a-jquery-ajax-call-with-confirm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#StatusChange").click(function () {

 var x=confirm( "Are you sure you want to delete?!");
           if(x){
            var state = 'ACTIVE';
            var id = '12345';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ChangeAccountStatus", "Account")',
                data: { currentStatus: state, accountId:id },
                success: function(data) 
                {
                   location.reload();
                }
            });
         }
   });
```

Sample:

```js
$("#StatusChange").click(function () {
       var num=$("#Num").val();
       var x=confirm( num==1?"Are you sure you want to delete?!":"Are you sure you want to Update?!");
       if(x){
        if(num==1) 
         $("div").remove();
        else
          $("div").text("test Update");
       }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Num" type="number" value="1"/>
<input type="button" id="StatusChange" value="delete"/>
<br>
<div>Test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, is there a way that I can change the text of confirm based on situation. I am using the same button to delete and add an account, i have a flag on what the button should do, the text should be like "Are you sure you want to delete?" if the flag (StatusId = 0) or "Are you sure you want to Add?" if the flag (StatusId = 1)

Comment: Yes You can first create a text based on the condition and store it in a variable, and then add the variable to the confirmation window.

Comment: i edited sample code . I hope that this sample will be useful

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Use standard javascript confirm dialog, like this:

```
$("#StatusChange").click(function () {
var result = confirm("Want to delete?");
if (result) {
    var state = 'ACTIVE';
    var id = '12345';    
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '@Url.Action("ChangeAccountStatus", "Account")',
          data: { currentStatus: state, accountId:id },
          success: function(data){location.reload();}
          });
}                
});
```

You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#StatusChange").click(function() {
  var state = 'ACTIVE';
  var id = '12345';

  if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this account?")) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("ChangeAccountStatus", "Account")',
      data: {
        currentStatus: state,
        accountId: id
      },
      success: function(data) {
        location.reload();
      }
    });
  }  // can optionally add an else statement here if user cancelled
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
$("#StatusChange").click(function () {

if(confirm("Are you sure you wish to continue?")){
            var state = 'ACTIVE';
            var id = '12345';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ChangeAccountStatus", "Account")',
                data: { currentStatus: state, accountId:id },
                success: function(data) 
                {
                   location.reload();
                }
            });
}
});
```